# CSS: SVG Border Image Broken Rendering

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

It seems Chrome renders SVG border images strangely...

Example code:
**html**

```css
   .border-img{
        margin:100px;
        width:100px;
        height:30px;
        border-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect width="30" height="30" rx="10" fill="red"/></svg>');
        border-image-slice: 40 40 40 40 fill;
        border-image-width: 10px;
        border-image-outset: 25px 10px;
        background-size: contain;
    }
    
    .border-img.ok {
        height: 31px
    }
```

```html
    <div class="border-img">test content</div>
    <div class="border-img ok">test content</div>
```

[image]

As you can see, the border of the upper item is broken, just because its height is `30px` while setting height to `31px` fixes everything.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6mydfczo/17/

Is there any trick to fix svg borders to render correctly regardless of container's size?

Comment: The svg element inside the url needs a width and a height. Since you have border-image-slice: 40 40 40 40 fill; I would use at least width="81" height="81".  Please read about [border-image](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/border-image/)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have to define **border property** first (border: 10px solid white;) and then you can apply border image. See Code snippet example.

**UPDATES**: decrease dividing source svg to it's viewbox size (in this case). There is some issues with slicing: too many divides can occur issue with rendering only corners. As I can see in [this MDN Web DOC page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice) (scroll down to the example), if you slide to adjust **border-image-slice=45** you will get your issue:

[image]

And even if you choose smaller number of slice it will be fine:

[image]

```css
/* applying box sizing */
*, ::after, ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.border-img {
  margin: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-image-source: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect width="30" height="30" rx="10" fill="red"/></svg>');
  border-image-slice: 30 fill; /* decrease dividing source svg */
  border-image-width: 10px;
  border-image-outset: 25px 10px;
  border-image-repeat: stretch;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="border-img">content 30</div>
  <div class="border-img" style="height: 31px;">content 31</div>
  <div class="border-img" style="height: 130px;">content 130</div>
  <div class="border-img" style="height: 130px; width: 200px;">content 130/200</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will increase the size of the boxes. 
enxaneta's comment has fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Got it, in this case I'll try to find better solution

Comment: @Adam I've made some investigations regarding that issue, so added some updates above. Also, in updated example there is no increasing of box sizes anymore. If interesting, you can take a look